# VK_API Node JS Задержка

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api

Помогите, пожалуйста, пишу бота для ВК и появился такой вопрос:
Как сделать, чтобы если бот отправил n сообщений за x секунд(или минут) то он прекращал работать b минут, а после чего автоматически запустился?
Если что использую VK-Promise, но можно и другие примеры.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Ну, у вас же есть какая-то функция отправки сообщений, поставьте счетчик сообщений и условие перед ней.

Comment: а как сделать чтобы счетчик обнулялся через какой-то промежуток времени?